# Inferring transition matrices in continuous time Markov processes

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-process, continuous-data

Suppose I have a process **X1**, for which I do not have a generator matrix, only a transition (probability) matrix **P1** for some time interval **T**, e.g. **T**=100. Suppose I have another process **X2**, such that **X2** is identical to **X1** except that if **X2** transitions to a state below a certain threshold, it is returned to one of the states above the threshold (with equal probability of each) at 1 time period thereafter, where 1 is the finest granularity time interval under consideration.

My question is, would there be any way to estimate a new transition matrix **P2** for **X2** (over time period **T**) directly from the old one, without the need to worry about the so-called embedding problem for Markov chains (or solving a quadratic optimisation to infer the best generator)?

To illustrate, if there are 3 states a-c above the threshold and another 3 states d-f below, then my known 1-period transition probabilities would be:

```
      a   b    c   d    e    f
    a[ .    .    .    .  .  .,
    b  .    .    .    .  .  .,
    c  .    .    .    .  .  .,
    d  1/3  1/3  1/3  0  0  0,
    e  1/3  1/3  1/3  0  0  0,
    f  0     0    0   0  0  1];
```

where '**f**' is an absorbing state. 
How would I use this information to obtain **P2** for the **T**-period case, given that I know **P1**?

Comment: Note: a unique generator may or may not exist for X1; I am only interested in obtaining a transition probability matrix P2 for X2.